# Processing Null values when connecting to a XLSX file through a Unstructed Data stage

Tags: datastage

When unloading Null values, the Datastage processes them as a string '#Null!'  instead of null. When unloading from xlsx, this does not happen.

I would like to get exactly the null value.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easy to change that in a Transformer afterwards?

Answer (score -1):

What are you referencing to in term of uploading Null value to like writing to a flat file using sequential stage?

Flat File doesn't have the concept of NULL, so you have to define it. NULL is only available in like RDBMS, etc.

Comment: When unloading an empty cell from an .xls file, I get a null value. When unloading from a xlsx file I get the string value '#NULL!'.
These are the default settings. I do not know how to change them

Comment: You mean reading or writing to .xls? Which stage are you using?